# "Facebook cannot be resolved to a type" in Facebook SDK for Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I followed the instruction on adding Facebook Android SDK to Eclipse, but for some reason when I restart eclipse I'm getting this error over and over again for all imported types from Facebook lib.

```
    "X cannot be resolved to a type"
```

Comment: Did you Closed eclipse by your self last time. if not try adding the facebook android sdk lib again to your project, in case if you could not find the reference in your project properties.

Comment: check the project's libraries.. in project properties..may be u must have changed the facebook library path later

Comment: mouseover Facebook facebook = ... and click setup project

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have done this step :

[image]

You press   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> to fix all the imports.